# Why use @babel/polyfill and also report API call errors

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs, polyfills

I am using @babel/polyfill for IE9 compatibility, the project uses react16, but when I use @babel/polyfill, I reported a setProptotypeOf is not a supported property or method, but I saw the packaged code, indeed do For compatibility processing, @babel/polyfill does take effect. Why is this problem still occurring?

react16, @babel/polyfill^7.4.4  webpack^4.19.1 babel^7.0.0

```
 entry: [
  "@babel/polyfill",
  ....
 ]
```

I expected that my project can runing well in IE9

Comment: Where is this `entry: [..]` bit? Inside `.babelrc`? Have you tried adding [targets](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-env#targets) to the config: `"targets": {
    "ie": "9"
  }`

Comment: `entry` should go into webpack config and the `targets: { "ie": "9" }` should go into `.babelrc` and you need to use `@babel/preset-env`.